# How to check if a file exist in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, fs, fs-extra

I'm on Nuxt 2.15.4 and i wanna check in my `store` codes if a file exist in nuxt directory by `fs-extra` package.

it is simple in modules because i can get files path by this code:

```js
const path = require('path')
const fse = require('fs-extra');
const FilePath = path.join(this.options.rootDir, './static/myfile.json')
const fse = require('fs-extra');
fse.pathExists(FilePath, (err, exists) => {
    console.log(err) // => null
    console.log(exists) // => true
})
```

but in `vuex store` i dont have access to `this.options.rootDir` and this code is always return false:

```js
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({dispatch, commit}) {
    if(process.server){
      const fse = require('fs-extra');
      fse.pathExists('~/static/myfile.json', (err, exists) => {
        console.log(err) // => null
        console.log(exists) // => false
      })
    }
  }
}
```

how can i get files fullpath or check if it exits??

#UPDATE

It looks like I had a little mistake in my file path so used `./static/myfile.json` and the check is done!!

but got another problem!! I have another json file, when I'm trying to use `Object.assign(mainfile, myfile)` it won't work!!

here is a sample:

```js
  async nuxtServerInit({dispatch, commit}) {
    let mainfile = require('../assets/mainfile.json')
    // if i use assign here it works and merge them together
    // let myfile = require('../assets/myfile.json')
    // Object.assign(mainfile, myfile)
    if(process.server){
      const fse = require('fs-extra');
      fse.pathExists('./static/myfile.json', (err, exists) => {
        if(exists){
          Object.assign(mainfile, myfile)
          commit('SET_FILE', mainfile); // this send the unmerged file to mutation
          console.log(mainfile); // but get the merged json here
        }
      })
      console.log(mainfile); // it is unmerged
    }
    console.log(mainfile); // it is unmerged
  }
```

Comment: ah my mistake!! should have used `./static/myfile.json` instead of `~/static/myfile.json` . was gonna delete my question but thought some one my need the solution. so don't down vote me plz :P

Comment: Best thing is to write an answer to your own question in this case (and to accept it). Totally fine. :)

Comment: @kissu , i updated my question. plz take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @kissu I found out the problem. As kissu mentioned in his answer's comment, `commit` is synchronous; I tried await action but didn't get the result; so I used `pathExistsSync` instead and done!!

```js
  async nuxtServerInit({dispatch, commit}) {
    let myfile = {}
    let mainfile = require('../assets/mainfile.json')
    if(process.server){
      const fse = require('fs-extra');
      if(fse.pathExistsSync('./static/myfile.json')){
          myfile = require('../assets/myfile.json')
          Object.assign(mainfile, myfile)
      }
    }
    await dispatch('setMyFile', mainfile)
  }
```

#Update

`require('../assets/mainfile.json')` still throw error if file doesn't exist even with `if(fse.pathExistsSync('./static/myfile.json'))` statement so:

```js
  async nuxtServerInit({dispatch, commit}) {
    let myfile = {}
    let mainfile = require('../assets/mainfile.json')
    if(process.server){
      const fse = require('fs-extra');
      if(fse.pathExistsSync('./static/myfile.json')){
          myfile = readJsonSync('./static/myfile.json')
          Object.assign(mainfile, myfile)
      }
    }
    await dispatch('setMyFile', mainfile)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For your updated question, be sure that `exists` is truthy, that you're entering in the loop and that `mainfile` is in the format that you're expecting.
Then, you could do

```js
mainfile = {...mainfile, ...myfile} // rather than Object.assign
```

Comment: i tracked all steps by `console.log()` and it looks like `process.server` part is running after @kissu the codes before & after it. the exist statement is true and i can log the result but cant commit vuex mutation. actually `console.log()` gives me the merged json before and after mutation in `fse.pathExists()` callback but the same data is send to mutation and its not merged!! look at the code part in UPDATE

Comment: Commits are synchronous, you should use a vuex action and call it like `await yourFancyVuexAction(mainfile)`.

Comment: thank you for your hint !! finally found the problem

Comment: i took advantage of your kindness and emailed u about another issue. plz check this if u have time. tanx : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67356435/how-to-copy-files-and-folders-using-fs-extra-in-nuxt